# unable to install apache-beam on macOS

Tags: python, apache-beam, python-wheel, fastavro

I'm trying to install apache-beam on my python vertical environment but it didn't work! I followed the steps provided by apache beam org [[Apache Beam Python SDK Quickstart]](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/#set-up-your-environment), but when executing

```
pip install apache-beam
```

I got this error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: fastavro
  Building wheel for fastavro (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/Shahad/Documents/Python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/6w/yphgql792sn8c7jwcqlb81xw0000gn/T/pip-install-cvn3kfvs/fastavro/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/6w/yphgql792sn8c7jwcqlb81xw0000gn/T/pip-install-cvn3kfvs/fastavro/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/6w/yphgql792sn8c7jwcqlb81xw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-jr5srm8k
       cwd: /private/var/folders/6w/yphgql792sn8c7jwcqlb81xw0000gn/T/pip-install-cvn3kfvs/fastavro/
  Complete output (29 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/_schema_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/_schema_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/write.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/_write_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/_read_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/_read_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/_validate_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/_validation_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/six.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/_timezone.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/const.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/schema.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/read.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  copying fastavro/validation.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  running build_ext
  building 'fastavro._read' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/envs/env1/include -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/envs/env1/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/Shahad/Documents/Python/include -I/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/envs/env1/include/python3.8 -c fastavro/_read.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro/_read.o
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastavro
```

> OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.4
>
> Python: 3.8.2

Anything to help? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xcrun%3A+error%3A+invalid+active+developer+path+missing+xcrun